# Transferring MS SQL database to other server - Best Practice

Tags: sql-server

What would be the best way to move a database from one server to another

a) Stop the database > Create a database backup > restore onto 'other server'

b) Detach the database > move the ldf and mdf files to new server and re-point database

Thanks

Comment: I am sure MS has detailed migration guides available. What do they say?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'd like the advice of others

Comment: It depends.  Backup and restore is the safest, but if you're moving 100+ databases (which I've done), you probably want to script something with detach-attach because it's faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I prefer:

**[Method 1: Back up and restore the user databases](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314546)**
Back up the user databases on the source server, and then restore the user databases to the destination server.

> The database can be used when the backup is in process. If users perform INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements on the database after the
>   backup is complete, the backup will not contain these changes. If you
>   must transfer all changes, you can transfer the changes with minimal
>   downtime if you perform both a transaction log backup and a full
>   database backup.
>           Restore the full database backup on the destination server and specify the WITH NORECOVERY option.
>
> Note To prevent additional database modifications, direct users to stop database activity on the source server.
>           Perform a transaction log backup and restore the transaction log backup to the destination server by using the WITH RECOVERY
>   option. Downtime is limited to the time of the transaction log backup
>   and restore. For more information, see the "RESTORE" sub-topic in the
>   "Transact-SQL Reference" topic of SQL Server Books Online.
>       The database on the destination server will be the same size as the database on the source server. To reduce the size of the database,
>   you must either reduce the source database before you perform the
>   backup, or reduce the destination database after the restore is
>   completed. For more information, see the "Shrinking a Database"
>   sub-topic in the "Creating and Maintaining Databases" heading of SQL
>   Server Books Online.
>       If you restore the database to a different file location than the source database, you must specify the WITH MOVE option. For example,
>   on the source server the database is in the D:\Mssql\Data folder. The
>   destination server does not have a D drive, and you want to restore
>   the database to the C:\Mssql\Data folder. For more information about
>   how to restore a database to a different location, click the following
>   article numbers to view the articles in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>       221465 Using the WITH MOVE option with the RESTORE statement
>       304692 Moving SQL Server 7.0 databases to a new location with BACKUP and RESTORE
>       If you want to overwrite a pre-existing database on the destination server, you must specify the WITH REPLACE option. For more
>   information, see the "RESTORE" sub-topic in the "Transact-SQL
>   Reference" topic of SQL Server Books Online.
>       Depending on the version of SQL Server to which you restore, the character set, sort order, and Unicode collation may have to be the
>   same on both the source and destination servers. For more information,
>   see the "Note about collation" later in this section.

I like that method because the old server stay functional in case the move don't work.

For further detail: [How to move databases between computers that are running SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314546)

Comment: The backup/restore feature would handle the databases themselves but not the security settings, accounts, agent jobs. You can transfer logins by using: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992 Not sure about the security settings/agent jobs

Comment: @JasonClark Yes, the KB I link talk about those move too, step 2 and more, if needed to do.